# How do we display document libraries in a tree view?

Tags: 2007, document-library

Normally when we click on any document library name, all the folders and files display in grid view format.

Can I change the grid view format to a tree view format and display all files and folders in single view only like virtual documents?

[image]

Comment: I have not install any 3rd party tool

Comment: Yes i do have admin permision on my site  & Central Administration also..

Comment: Marek , i used that image only to get clear explaination..

Answer (score 2):

You can mimmic this virtual documents view by using metadata fields to create grouped views.  It isn't as tidy as this 3rd party tool, but the options are available out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

This tree view is **not a standard SharePoint feature**. It is provided by [**docBlock Ascend**](http://www.blackbladeinc.com/en-us/products/docBlock/Pages/default.aspx) solution. I've never used it, but I suppose it adds new document library type - *Virtual Documents*. The tree view is only available for libraries of this type.